# How to efficiently stream words and whitespace from a large text file

Tags: performance-tuning, string-manipulation

I want to tokenize a large (~20 MB) file, opening it and streaming the words, but preserving the whitespace as well. Example:

```
stream = StringToStream["abc  def g\n  hi"]
readToken[stream]
   => {"", "abc"}
readToken[stream]
   => {"  ", "def"}
readToken[stream]
   => {" ", "g"}
readToken[stream]
   => {"\n  ", "hi"}
```

A word here is just a sequence of non-whitespace characters (space and newline). `Read[stream, Word]` nearly does the job, but discards the intervening whitespace. (I want to be able to reconstruct the file byte-for-byte from the tokens.) I know how to do it by reading lines at a time and using `StringCases`, but this doesn't handle the newlines well, is probably not very fast, and also uses global state to parcel out the results across later calls of the function. What is an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: I think, `ReadString[stream, " "|"\n"]` is a reasonable place to start tweaking.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I think you have something there, but it acts strangely. I tried some tests with it, and it has some weird async stuff going on. In my tests I would often end up with old data from the previous test prepended to the string returned from `ReadString`, even if I closed all streams and cleared all variables before the test. Also the value returns sometimes after other print statements, even though it claims to be a blocking function. Finally, the `StreamPosition` ends up at the end of the file after one read, which is very strange. If you can overcome these though you may have a winner.

Comment: yes, @mario, I've noted the same strange behavior and it's not covered by the documentation too well. The documentation also says, it can take string patterns as terminators, although I had to do stuff like `Alternatives[Whitespace,Whitespace]` instead of just `Whitespace` and still I got the buggy behavior. I know, that `ReadString` requires a file to be opened with the `BinaryFormat` option, but I don't really understand how they all interact with one another. Like I said, the docs are poor on this functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but my pingbacks, if inserted at the beginning of a comment are getting removed from the message, so here's another one @mario

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I also noticed the pattern problem; it can also be fixed by naming the pattern e.g. `x:Whitespace`. Regarding pingbacks, the `@Mario` is removed because I am the OP so I get notified even if you don't put the @ sign. If you want to use my name at the beginning of a sentence, just drop the @.

Comment: Oh, right, I've completely overlooked the fact, that I'm answering under your post. Naming patterns is an interesting suggestion, I'll test this out. It'll be interesting to see, how my latest answer benchmarks on your dataset.

Comment: Also, I think I've realized, what's going on with `ReadString` and patterns. ``<<GeneralUtilities`;PrintDefinitions[ReadString]`` offers insight as to why it fails and pushes the `StreamPosition` to the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is conceptually similar to that of Mario (aka OP), but I think, is in a way cleaner, uses more built-in functionality to get the right form straight away. Kudos to Leonid, from whom I've learned a nice application of `Reap` today in some other thread.

Anyway, here's the simpler code without an `EndOfFile` check:

```
readToken[stream_] := Join @@
  Reap[

   While[StringMatchQ[Sow[Read[stream, Character]], WhitespaceCharacter]]; 
   SetStreamPosition[stream, StreamPosition[stream] - 1]; 
   Read[stream, {Word}],

   _,

   "" <> Most@#2 &] // Reverse (* arguments of Reap separated by blank lines for clarity *)
```

This returns an error should the `EOF` be reached, but otherwise should probably be faster as there are less intermediate calculations.

Some kind of check for the `EOF` can be implemented like so:

```
smQ[EndOfFile] := EndOfFile
smQ[s_String] := StringMatchQ[s, WhitespaceCharacter]
readToken2[stream_] :=
 Reap[
     While[smQ[Sow[Read[stream, Character]]]]; 
     SetStreamPosition[stream, StreamPosition[stream] - 1]; 
     Read[stream, {Word}],

     _,

     If[Last@#2 === EndOfFile,
       {"" <> Most@#2, EndOfFile},
       "" <> Most@#2] &] // Reverse // Flatten // #[[;; 2]] &
```

This seems to work quite well, though I'm not sure, how much overhead is caused by all these checks (quite a lot, actually!).

Here's another version, that should be fast, handles `EoF`, using global variable as a flag for reaching `EoF`.

```
Unprotect[EndOfFile];
EndOfFile /: StringMatchQ[EndOfFile, _] := ($ = 1; False)
    Protect[EndOfFile];
    $=0;
readToken3[stream_] := 
Flatten@Reap[
While[StringMatchQ[Sow[Read[stream, Character]], 
  WhitespaceCharacter]];
SetStreamPosition[stream, StreamPosition[stream] - 1 + $];
Read[stream, {Word}], _, "" <> Most@#2 &] // Reverse
```

Of course, once the `EoF` is reached, the flag `$` is set to 1 and needs to be reverted back to 0 before using `readToken3` again.

Comment: Your first solution is indeed very fast; I used `Timing@While[Check[readToken[stream]; True, False]]` and got 45.2 seconds, almost as good as `Read[_, Word]`'s 11 seconds. The second solution benchmarked at 185.7 seconds. Maybe there is a way to use `Check` on the first solution and switch over to the second to satisfy the spec.

Comment: @Mario Yes, I think that would be trivial, actually. For example, `Check[$current=readToken[stream],parse[$current]]` where `parse` is some function designed to massage the output with the error messages into the correct form. Alternatively, you could measure the byte-length of the file being read and check the value of `StreamPosition`. If it reaches the end of the file, then again just apply `parse` to the latest result.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro also the checks I provide in my second example are inefficient and should be implemented either through `UpValues` of `EndOfFile` or by reordering the definitions. The problem is, that an attempt to match `smQ[input]` to `smQ[EndOfFile]` is tried first, and only then the string pattern is checked. Similar considerations hold for the `If` statement.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I've added a very primitive check that should lead to minimal overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `Read[_, Word]`-based solution using `StreamPosition` and `SetStreamPosition`. For some silly reason `ReadList[stream, _, 0]` returns unevaluated instead of `{}`, so it had to be special-cased. `StringJoin@ReadList[stream, Character, n]` doesn't seem like the most efficient way to read a fixed-length string from a stream, but it's the only one I can find.

```
readToken[stream_] := 
 Module[{p = StreamPosition[stream], p2, w, l, r}, 
  w = Read[stream, Word];
  If[w === EndOfFile, EndOfFile,
   l = StringLength[w]; 
   p2 = StreamPosition[stream];
   SetStreamPosition[stream, p]; 
   r = {If[# == 0, "", StringJoin@ReadList[stream, Character, #]] &[p2 - p - l], w};
   SetStreamPosition[stream, p2]; r]]
```

This benchmarks at 125.3 seconds for my test file (28816342 bytes, 3750496 words), a bit better than Aisamu's 693 second char-by-char method.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[readToken]
readToken[stream_] := 
    readToken[stream, {}, Read[stream, Character]]
readToken[stream_, list : {whites : (" " | "\n") ..., chars : Except[(" " | "\n")] ..}, " " | "\n"] := 
    (SetStreamPosition[stream, StreamPosition[stream] - 1]; 
    {StringJoin@whites, StringJoin@chars})
readToken[stream_, list : {whites : (" " | "\n") ..., chars : Except[(" " | "\n")] ...}, EndOfFile] :=
    {StringJoin@whites, StringJoin@chars} /. {"", ""} -> EndOfFile
readToken[stream_, list_, newElem_] := 
    readToken[stream, Append[list, newElem], Read[stream, Character]]
```

Since the stream is consumed on a character-basis, there's probably little memory pressure. A benchmark against your current code is recommended!

#### Sample string results

```
stream = StringToStream["abc  def g\n  hi"];
Do[readToken[stream] // InputForm // Print, {6}]

(*
{"", "abc"}
{"  ", "def"}
{" ", "g"}
{"\n  ", "hi"}
EndOfFile
EndOfFile
*)
```

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know about `SetStreamPosition`; that opens a lot more options. The biggest issue with this method is that it is quite slow; `Timing@While[readToken[stream] =!= EndOfFile]` gives 693 seconds over 11.87 seconds for `Timing@While[Read[stream, Word] =!= EndOfFile]` (although that's probably not a fair comparison since `Read[_,Word]` is built in). Perhaps `ReadList` with a decent buffer size would improve the number of individual IO calls.

Comment: That, and also that reading a stream byte by byte is bound to be slower than reading it by larger chunks. But it is not really useful to benchmark against something that does not meet the specification! I tried before with `Read[_,Word]`, but there were so many small issues that I gave up and went for  `Read[_,`Character`] instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to "fix" `ReadString` to work properly with `x:WordBoundary` patterns, with minimal modification of any private symbols. None, in fact. Be wary, that internally, `ReadString` does `BinaryReadStrin[stream, "Character8", 10000]` and then uses standard string manipulation functions on the result, whereas `Read[stream, Word]` is, apparently, not written in Mathematica code. I'm really not sure, if `ReadString` is intrinsically fast in this respect.

Anyways, the problem with using a pattern like `WordBoundary` to read in the next word is that a string like `"blahblah \n \t stuff"` has a `WordBoundary` at position `{1,0}`, then at position `{9,8}`. One could think, that we should do repeatedly

```
{ReadString[stream, x:WordBoundary], Read[stream, Word]}
```

but that's not the case. See the linked thread for details. As Mario commented "it has some weird async stuff going on". Specifically, `ReadString` reads a big chunk of 10000 bytes in, saves this to a buffer and then works through the buffer, before reading in the next chunk. `Read`, on the other hand, reads stuff in from the current `StreamPosition`, which, after calling `ReadString` is already at the `EoF`.

I suppose, these are some limitation of reading stuff in in a binary format or something. This means, that if I want to use `ReadString`, then I can only use **its** functionality, and not that of `Read`.

When I do the call `ReadString[stream, x:WordBoundary]`, it runs some internal checks, then calls `` ProcessLink`Private`genericGetString[stream, (*pattern*), (*timeConstraint*)] ``.

If I want to read in the next sequence of whitespace, that's ok, because the first position at which a `WordBoundary` is found is not at the beginning of the string. If I want to read in the next word, I have a problem, because then I'm not interested in the boundary at the start of the string, but rather the one following it.

Thus, I roll my own variant of `genericGetString` that does what I want, stealing most of the code from the original definition of `genericGetString`.

```
Begin["ProcessLink`Private`"]
Global`ReadString2[st_, patt_] := genericGetString2[st, patt];
genericGetString2[st_, patt_] := Module[{str, buff = "", pos = {}},
   While[
    pos === {},
    str = cachedReadString[st];
    If[! StringQ[str],
     Return[If[buff === "", str, Message[ReadString::notfound]; buff]]
     ];
    buff = buff <> str;
    pos = StringPosition[buff, patt];];
   If[pos =!= {},
    setStreamCache[st, StringDrop[buff, pos[[2, 2]]]]; 
    StringTake[buff, pos[[2, 1]] - 1],
    buff]
   ];
End[];
```

What I have done here, is throw the time constraint checks out the window, but most importantly, in the 3rd and 4th lines from the bottom I have changed `pos[[1,2]] -> pos[[2,2]]` and `pos[[1,1]] -> pos[[2,1]]`.

This now works:

```
readToken[str_] := 
  {ReadString[str, x:(WordBoundary|EndOfString)],
       ReadString2[str, x:(WordBoundary|EndOfString)]}
```

The result for the start of the stream is

```
{(* whitespace, even if of length 0 *), (* first word *)}
```

The result at the end of the stream is

```
{(* whitespace preceding last word *), (* last word *)}
{(* whitespace following last word, if none - EndOfFile *), EndOfFile}
```

This method fails if the value of `` ProcessLink`Private`binaryReadBlock `` is too small. One would think, that if the procedure doesn't find, what it's looking for, it would append another chunk to the current cache, but this seems to not be the case. Maybe later I'll have a stab at fixing this oversight too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ReadList`

```
ReadList[stream, "String"]
(*{"abc  def g", "  hi"}*)
```

You can specify number of lines(records) to read as the third parameter, if you need to prevent overflow.

If you need to separate this into words, you can then use `StringSplit`

Comment: I don't want to read the entire file in, just word by word. It also has to return the words one at a time, unless there is a way to do a C# `yield return` -type trick in the middle of a `Scan[]`. Also this doesn't preserve newlines.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro to get one line, You can specify number of lines(records) to read as the third parameter, `StringSplit /@ ReadList[stream, "String",1]` Gives you all words on a given line

Comment: This is a long way from a workable solution. How is this supposed to remember its state so that calls to `nextToken` give the next word and not the next line or the same word, or the list of all words? I know about `Read` (the `List` is not necessary, since we only want one word at a time) and I already explained in the OP why it (alone) doesn't fit my needs.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro you need to edit and clarify your question

Comment: I thought the specification was fairly clear. How would you define `readToken` so that it behaves as in the example? Sorry to be so harsh, but I'm concerned about your current non-answer taking the Q off the unanswered queue and dissuading others from providing their own answers.