# `ReadString` and `StreamPosition` behaving strangely with custom terminators

Tags: string-manipulation, streams, parsing

I've stumbled on a strange behavior while trying to use custom terminators for `ReadString`.

When I use a simple `String` as the terminator, I get the following behavior

```
stream = StringToStream[" abc  def g\n  hi"]
Do[{
   StreamPosition[stream],
   ReadString[stream, StringExpression[" "] // FullForm,
   StreamPosition[stream]
   } // Print
 , {6}]

(*
{0, "abc", 4}
{4, "def", 9}
{9, "g\n", 12}
{12, "hi", 16}
{16, EndOfFile, 16}
{16, EndOfFile, 16}
*)
```

Everything OK here. It looks as the default is to discard empy "reads". If I use, instead, a simple `Alternative` things behave very differently.

```
stream = StringToStream[" abc  def g\n  hi"]
Do[{
    StreamPosition[stream],
    ReadString[stream, StringExpression[" " | EndOfString]] // FullForm,
    StreamPosition[stream]
    }
  , {9}]

(*
{0, "", 16}
{16, "abc", 16}
{16, "", 16}
{16, "def", 16}
{16, "g\n", 16}
{16, "", 16}
{16, "hi", 16}
{16, EndOfFile, 16}
{16, EndOfFile, 16}
*)
```

Not only empty records are now presented, but the `StreamPosition` mechanism becomes useless.

I suppose the string is being read in it's entirety on the second example, but why? There is no ambiguity in the separator, and no need for look-aheads if the parser matches a single `" "`.

And is there a reason for empty records to be returned by default only on the second example?

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I was pondering the very same problem, the related question is http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108814/26956 . I'd like to add, that this problem originates from a desire to have not only the functionality `Read[strm, Word, 1]` but also `Read[strm, WhitespaceSequence, 1]`. `ReadString[strm, Except[WhitespaceCharacter]` seemed like a good solution to me, however MMA does not like this kind of string pattern in `ReadString`.

Comment: Note that `ReadString[strm, StringExpression[Except[WhitespaceCharacter]]` works, if you're willing to accept the idiosyncrasies I've pointed above!

Comment: If only `ReadString` could also *return* the terminator... I think, part of the problem is constantly setting the stream position.

Comment: Btw, your first block has a syntax error (unmatched brackets) and after a kernel restart on my machine does not return proper `StreamPosition`s, that you show in the example output, but rather suffers from the same problem as the second example.

Answer (score 3):

This is for the moment an incomplete answer, but I gathered lots of insight by using

```
<<GeneralUtilities`
PrintDefinitions[ReadString]
```

`ReadString` internally calls a functions that reads the stream in in chunks of `10 000` characters. It also updates the (down)value of `` ProcessLink`Private`$StreamCache[stream] `` on the fly. It contains the remainder of the chunk, that was not returned by `ReadString`.

The magical value of `10 000` is contained in a variable called `` ProcessLink`Private`binaryReadBlock ``. By changing this number

```
ProcessLink`Private`binaryReadBlock = 2
```

we get an interesting result:

```
stream = StringToStream["abc  def g\n  hi"];
StreamPosition[stream]
ReadString[stream, x : WhitespaceCharacter]
StreamPosition[stream]
(* 0 *)
(* "abc" *)
(* 4 *)
```

And then (this is more relevant to the original problem)

```
ReadString[stream, x : Except[WhitespaceCharacter]]
StreamPosition[stream]
(* " " *)
(* 6 *)
```

But now run this again:

```
StreamPosition[stream]
ReadString[stream, x : WhitespaceCharacter]
StreamPosition[stream]
(* 6 *)
(* "ef" *)
(* 10 *)
```

One would expect 9, but that's not the case. We are now reading in blocks of 2 characters at a time. The first block had `"ef"` and contained no `Whitespace` so another block was read (`" g"`). It was added to the cache, the leading space was dropped, but the `StreamPosition` got shifted to 10. `ReadString` pulls data from the cache and using `SetStreamPosition` is apparently highly unreliable. Unfortunately, it does not play nicely with patterns of the type `x:WordBoundary` (which is relevant to the original QA), but I'm sure, that with careful study of the internals, an implementation can be made, that will work correctly. This will eliminate the need to `SetStreamPosition`.

Comment: This means that the issue I noticed with results from the previous test bleeding over to later tests must be caused by `ProcessLink\`Private\`$StreamCache[stream]` not getting cleared on `Close[stream]` (which would not be a problem except that the "unique ID" for closed streams is reused for later streams). That sounds like a reportable bug.